# Why does this error happen? "npm run dev missing script error"

Tags: node.js, npm, phaser-framework

I've been trying to follow the following tutorial:
https://github.com/digitsensitive/phaser3-typescript/blob/master/README.md

These are the steps that I had to follow

Prerequisites
Download and install npm with Node.js @ https://nodejs.org/en
Installing
Select a folder, navigate to it, and clone this repository with this command-line:

```
git clone https://github.com/digitsensitive/phaser3-typescript.git
```

Install the dependencies with this command-line:

```
npm install
```

If you use yarn just replace npm with yarn

Building and Running
Perform a quick build (bundle.js) and start server:
npm run dev

I've never used node.js and npm before so I'm stumbling across some newbie mistakes. One error I get is that when I try to run npm run dev, Git bash returns the following error code:

```
npm ERR! missing script: dev

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli 'run',
1 verbose cli 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: dev
4 verbose stack at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:418:5
4 verbose stack at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:373:45)
4 verbose stack at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:416:3)
4 verbose stack at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack at ReadFileContext. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:237:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Yassi\TEST
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
```

I don't know what I should be adding to my package.json file to make this work. Could anyone help me with this please?

I made a package.json using init, but the tutorial doesn't state that I have to do this. I don't know why I should manually make a package.json file in the first place.

Comment: Did you cd into the cloned folder?

Comment: I didn't but now I'm getting other errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package.json is missing  a "dev" key in the scripts section.
Or you are running the npm command from a wrong directory. 
Please use a package.json  from their project. I think this will work

From here:
https://github.com/digitsensitive/phaser3-typescript?files=1

Comment: You were right. I ran the npm command in the wrong directory. But now I'm getting another error:
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:8080

Now I'm getting multiple errors that I don't know how to fix

Comment: I got a log file which says the following:
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error phaser3-typescript@1.2.4 dev: `webpack --mode development && webpack-dev-server --mode development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the phaser3-typescript@1.2.4 dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: It looks like another process running on port 8080, try killing it  or change the webpack dev server port in webpack.config.js.

 devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8080,  // <---  choose your own port here
    open: true
  }
Also please run npm command as administrator.

Comment: It was! I turned off the other process that was running on port 8080 and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Just add div in scripts object in your `package.json` file
as you see

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
      "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"
    },
```

that's if you use **nodemon** package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).